# Combining jQuery delay and windowTimeout for CSS based fade ins one after another

Tags: jquery, css, timeout, jquery-animate, addclass

swinging the big bat here and going modern-only on a personal project. Elements are loaded on the page with `opacity:0` and will have a class added to them that has `opacity:1` and a CSS3 transition. I'm trying to cue each of the elements to fade in one after another.

Typically, I can use the below code to cue fade ins, but this uses jQuery's `.animate()` method and I want higher frame rates and less CPU strain.

```
$('.test').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i*100).animate({ opacity:1 }, 400); //CPU based!
});
```

Adding a class is almonst instantaneous (to us humans) and therefore the effect doesn't do all that much.

```
$('.test').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i*100).addClass('show'); //instant coffee!
});
```

The goal then is setting a timeout after the class is added so that it effectively takes the same time the original animation would. **And herein lies my problem:** The `setTimeout()` method can only be run on the window...

```
$('.test').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i*100).setTimeout(function(){ //doesn't work!
        $(this).addClass('show');
    }, 400);
});
```

How can I delay each elements function and give the `addClass()` method some hang time?

```
$('.test').each(function(i) {
    var test = $(this);

    test.delay(i*100,function(){ //I wish!
        setTimeout(function(){
            test.addClass('show');
        },400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('.test').each(function(i) {
    var ind = i * 100;
    var test = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        test.addClass('show');
    }, ind);
});
```

or:

```
var $tests = $('.test')
var len = $tests.length;
var i = 0;
var test =  setInterval(function(){
                $tests.eq(i).delay(i*100).queue(function(){
                  $(this).addClass('show')
                })   
                i++;
                if (i == len) {
                    clearInterval(test)
                }
             }, 400)
```